# why do i get a NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I've set up my config to use Mailtrap on Heroku and can confirm that I've got the bulk of it set up. Meaning I receive the emails, but only so long as I don't call methods on the user model. Personalizing the emails with `@user.name` and automating the user it sends to with `@user.email` results in a no method error. I thought maybe it had something to do with the fact that I'm sending emails from the user model instead of my customized devise users controller, so I added a create method to that. Which did nothing. The error says `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass`

In my user model I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :new_user
 validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, if: -> { self.email.present? }

 private
    def new_user
      UserMailer.new_user(@user).deliver_now
    end
end
```

In my user mailer I have

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

    def new_user(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'You will be notified when your account is activated.')
    end
end
```

And then in my users controller, which is extended from Devise::RegistrationsController, I have

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def create
  @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
 end

 private
    def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :approved)
    end
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, how embarrassing. It was returning nil because I wasn't telling it to use the most recently created record. Changing `@user = user` to `@user = User.last` in my mailer solved it. T_T